# Downgrading from a pirated Windows OS

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1

In the past, because of the hype, I have upgraded to a pirated version of Windows 10. Coming from a Licensed Windows 8.1.

Now I'm wondering if I can still comeback to Windows 8.1 using my product key.
Because I want to get the Free Windows 10 Upgrade.

Would it be possible to use my product key again??

Comment: What type of OS you have OEM or Volume Licence etc...

Comment: @vembutech i think its OEM. it came with my Win 8.1 CD..

Comment: You have your Win 8.1 DVD and Licence Key? If you have you can install it

Comment: How did you manage to pirate Windows 10, if you had a licensed version of Windows 8.1, when a licensed version of Windows 10 was not only FREE but an upgrade offered to you?  Download Windows 10 Version 1511 .ISO, format your system, when asked for a license hit "skip" Windows 10 will automatically activate based on the embedded license key.  There is no reason to install Windows 8.1, its not needed, Widows 10 will accept and detect your license key at installation, and activate automatically once installed.  Just use the right version ( Home vs Professional vs Single Language, vs ect. )

Comment: Make and Model of PC would be helpful for advice on reinstalling W8.

Comment: @Hexxed - Why does everyone think you have to be offered the upgrade? All you literally have to do is download the .ISO, on a valid activated eligible copy of Windows, and you will have a valid activated installation of Windows 10.  So all you had to do originally, from within Windows 8.1, was to upgrade to Windows 10.  So basically pirating Windows 10, all that did, was just make it so you can't trust installation otherwise you could activate it as-is.

Comment: @Ramhound I was not offered for a free update (or not yet offered). (i think because I built my PC myself) But I was eager to get one and cant wait to have one ASAP. So I went rogue and pirated Win10. I think I cant directly install another Win10 because the key im currently using is pirated.

Comment: You don't have to be "offered" the update.  I will repeat for the third time.  All you had to do was, from within Windows 8.1, upgrade to Windows 10 the .ISO is freely available to everyone.  If you built your PC, all you have to do, is to change the product key to your Windows 8.1 product key.  I built my PC I was offered the update, i decided I wanted to use the .ISO, to avoid upgrading 10 computers automatically.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for the clarifications. Yes I'm currently downloading the Win10 ISO. I'll just downgrade to 8.1 and reformat the mess I made. Please Place the your comment in the answers so I can accept it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already mangled your existing operating system by upgrading to a pirated version of Windows 10. Use your Windows 8.1 disk to do a new installation of your original Windows 8.1 operating system. If you have saved the product key from your original Windows 8.1 operating system, then use that product key again to install Windows 8.1.

You can downgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 8, by following the instructions in the answers to this question: [How can I downgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/926068/how-can-i-downgrade-from-windows-10-to-windows-8). Why not downgrade the pirated Windows 10 to Windows 8 instead and then change the product key and upgrade legally back to Windows 10? There are two reasons for not doing it this way:

1. Your new Windows 10 can inherit problems from the pirated version of Windows 10.
2. It's a two-step process to install Windows 8.1 and upgrade to Windows 10 instead of a four-step cumulative history: Windows 8.1 -> pirated Windows 10 -> downgrade pirated Windows 10 to Windows 8.1 -> upgrade to Windows 10. Even though the two-step method doesn't save any time, it still eliminates two unnecessary steps.

Comment: So Basically,  If I understood you correctly, I need to reformat then install Win8.1 then Legally License it and then Upgrade to Win10? I already Have my Win10 ISO file from microsoft.

Comment: Yes, you have understood me correctly.

Comment: UPDATE: I'm already running Windows 8.1 with License. However, when I use my windows 10 1511 ISO. It still asks for my product key. I try to enter my keys but it didnt take it.

Comment: Because the Windows 10 1511 ISO didn't accept the product key, you could make sure that you have activated Windows 8.1 and then upgrade to Windows 10 directly from inside Windows 8.1. The latest version of Windows 10 is Version 1511 (OS build 10.0.10586.164) (released March 8, 2016). [Help with upgrading to Windows 10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/help-upgrade-windows-10)

Comment: I'm sure its activated. I don't want to use `MediaCreationTool` because my download speeds are slow. I mounted the iso file then used the setup.exe.

Comment: Your slow download speed is not mission critical, because you can also download the Microsoft Media Creation Tool, which can be to create a USB or DVD and install Windows 10, on a different PC. By "on a different PC" I mean that you can create a USB or DVD from a location that has a faster download speed, like an internet cafe. The instructions for doing this, including a screenshot, are in [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/1003471/how-do-i-go-from-windows-8-1-directly-to-windows-10-v-1511-on-my-hp-stream-7/1003505#1003505).

Answer (score 1):

You can directly perform a clean install of Windows 10 by getting the iso from here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

From version 1511, Windows 10 installation allows you to use directly your Windows 8.1 key (the legal one) to activate your free upgrade copy of Windows 10 from that licence.

As it is a clean install, there won't be anything left from the pirated one.

Comment: This could be another way for me to go. I'm still researching.